# Calculation of $\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\,d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $l>0$ be a fixed parameter I want to calculate

$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}\operatorname{arctanh}\sin\theta\,d\theta$$

for that i wrote $$\operatorname{arctanh}\sin\theta=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Then $$\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}\operatorname{arctanh}\sin\theta\,d\theta=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}\frac{(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\,d\theta$$

Then we should calculate $$\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\,d\theta$$ but i don't know how to do that. Please help me

Thanks

Comment: this is what i tried to do\begin{align}
\sin^{2n+1}(\theta)
&=\left(\frac1{2i}\right)^{2n+1}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)^{2n+1}\\
&=\left(\frac1{2i}\right)\left(-\frac14\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}e^{i(2n+1-k)\theta}e^{-ik\theta}(-1)^k\\
&=\left(\frac1{2i}\right)\left(\frac14\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}e^{i(2n+1-2k)\theta}(-1)^{n-k}
\end{align}

Comment: That is not right!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

For your original problem there is no need to calculate $\enspace\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\,d\theta \enspace $ .

---

$\displaystyle f(\ell):=\int_{0}^{\arcsin\tanh\ell}\operatorname{arctanh}\sin\theta\,d\theta \enspace\enspace => \enspace\enspace f'(\ell)=\frac{\ell}{\cosh \ell}$

We get:

$\displaystyle f(\ell)= 2 \left(C  - \Im(\text{Li}_2(i/e^\ell)) - \ell \cot^{-1}(e^\ell) \right) $

where $\,C\,$ is the *Catalan constant* (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant )

and $\,\cot^{-1}\,$ the inverse of $\,\cot\enspace$ ; $\enspace\Im($...$)$ means the *imaginary part of ...*

and $\enspace \text{Li}_2(z)\enspace$ is the *Dilogarithm* (or *Spence's*) function

(e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html)